# jQuery syntax while using master Page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-selectors, master-pages

I am using master page where i need to move value of one listbox to the other with the help of jQuery I tried many ways but wasn't able to hit the nail.

The methods I tried are as follows:

```
$("[id$='ModuleMasterListBox option:[@selected]']").appendTo($("[id$='ModuleSelectListBox']"));

$("[id$='ModuleMasterListBox option:@selected]'").appendTo($("[id$='ModuleSelectListBox']"));

var module = $("[id$='ModuleMasterListBox']").val();
module.appendTo($("[id$='ModuleSelectListBox']"));
```

These are the methods I tried which failed - please help me out....

Comment: Could you please show some HTML, and also tell us what you mean by "failed"? Did your code do *some* thing, but not *the* thing? Did it not do *any* thing? Did it throw evil errors at you that would make even the toughest knight cry like a baby?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
$("[id$='ModuleMasterListBox'] :selected").appendTo("[id$='ModuleSelectListBox']");
```

From your markup and the `@` sign it looks like you're using an outdated version of jQuery, you may want to [consider upgrading](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).  In the above we're using the [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to get the `<select>` the using [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to grab the selected `<option>` before moving it.

Keep in mind since it looks like you're using ASP.Net this will *by default* throw validation errors on the server-side, you'll have to disable page validation for it to allow items it didn't bind.